# How do I communicate over wifi with a wired device that can't use DHCP?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

Basically I have a device (device1) which can only communicate with things wirelessly via a wifi network and must receive its IP address via DHCP. I would like to use device1 to communicate with another device (device2) which is incapable of any sort of wireless or DHCP and must communicate via ethernet using a hard-coded static IP address. I am trying to use a tp-link AC1750 router in order to create a wifi network in which device1 is connected wirelessly and dynamically receives an IP address, while device2 is hardwired and uses its own static IP address. Is there a way to do this? Is there a better way to do this than via a router?

I don't need any sort of internet connection, just an internal communication between these two devices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, just make sure both devices have an IP address in the same subnet and the wired (fixed IP) device is outside of the DHCP range.

I.e. if your router has address 192.168.x.1 and your DHCP range (for example) is 192.168.x.2 - 192.168.x.100 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, then your fixed IP device can have any address in the range of 192.168.x.101 - 192.168.x.254.

Where x can be any number between 0 and 255, preferably not conflicting with other ranges in your home, if you ever need to connect them.

Make sure you configure the router to let wireless devices connected to it be able go communicate with wired devices.

Connect the wired device to one of the router’s regular switch ports, not to the WAN/Internet port.